# Double quote (") + str_replace() for double slash and more than double slash + json_decode() not working when i pass double quote in json value

Tags: php, json

I am getting data into $data like this

```
$data=json_decode(str_replace("\\","",$_GET['data']));
```

In this way it will give me blank data.

It will work if i will pass it like this

```
$data=json_decode($_GET['data']);
```

But issue with this thing added \ in my string more and more every time when i will execute it.

I am passing json like this in $_GET['data']:

```
[
{
"id":"1",
"about":"about_details",
"biodata":"Always \"happy",
"sharedetails":"\\\\New happening\"",
"fname":"username"
}
]
```

I don't want to remove double quotes `"` into my string also i want to remove double slashes`\\` . Please provide me a better solution

Answer (score 0):

Use four slashes like this

```
 $data=json_decode(str_replace("\\\\","",$_GET['data']));
```

What is happening here is that you are escaping your slashes. Essentially, `\\` means one slash  while `\\\\` would mean two slashes. str_replace with three slashes will cause a parse error because you are escaping a quote.

Working example:  http://www.tehplayground.com/#1UjQOXT2W

As you specified only one slash (`\\`), you were replacing every occurrence of a single slash in you string. This resulted in

> {"id":"1","about":"about_details","biodata":"Always
>   "happy","sharedetails":"New happening"","fname":"username"}

Note two quotation signs after New happening. This is not a valid json string that is impossible to decode

Comment: as per my question it will works file if i am not passing " in any value but if i passed it into any value it will not work because of str_replace() if i will try after removing str_replace it will work perfectly but give me \\ more in my string

Comment: You have an escaped quotation in New happening. If you remove the slash from the string, it becomes not escaped, and therefore breaks the whole string

Comment: as per your suggestion to add \\\\ it will works but it added single \ before "

Comment: so this is not proper solution if it will give me only double quote in output(") than ok but it will give me \"